# Concat/Push Object keys to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

I have the following problem to concat multiple object values into one Array!

My current code:

```
const coins = [];
Object.keys(prices).forEach((key) => {
    coins.push(prices[key]);
    console.log("prices", prices);
    console.log("prices[key]", prices[key]);
    console.log("coins", coins);
});
```

Output:

```
prices { ETH: { USD: 1332.03 }, BTC: { USD: 14602.09 } }
prices[key] { USD: 1332.03 }
coins [ { USD: 1332.03 } ]
prices { ETH: { USD: 1332.03 }, BTC: { USD: 14602.09 } }
prices[key] { USD: 14602.09 }
coins [ { USD: 1332.03 }, { USD: 14602.09 } ]
```

What needs to be achieved:

```
coins =  [ 1339.64, 14617.95 ]
```

I only need the values to do mathematical operations with them.

Comment: You're pushing the object in, change to `coins.push(prices[key].USD);`

Comment: Actually, why is your desired result different figures? `coins =  [ 1339.64, 14617.95 ]` you start with 1332.03 & 14602.09

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pushing the `USD` property would do:

```
coins.push(prices[key].USD);
```

But you can do it better:

```
Object.values(prices).map(price => price.USD);
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, push the USD price in instead of the whole object:

```js
const coins = [];
const prices = {
  ETH: {
    USD: 1332.03
  },
  BTC: {
    USD: 14602.09
  }
};
Object.keys(prices).forEach((key) => {
  coins.push(prices[key].USD); /* <- here is the change, add the key of the price */
  console.log("prices", prices);
  console.log("prices[key]", prices[key]);
  console.log("coins", coins);
});
```